# MySql Table Insert if not exist otherwise update Without having unique keys or the primary key

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

problem i have :

```
UPDATE data SET year="2017", mark='0133', Timestamp="2010-01-14 23:30:00.000"
WHERE year="2017" AND mark='0133';
```

It works if the year and mark exists, but I want to insert this data as a new row if the does not exist.

ON DUPLICATE KEY not work because, year and mark are indexed, but they are not unique keys or primary keys.

**Update:**

i dont know if i can run it as a query in PDO:

```
DECLARE @numrecords INT

SELECT @numrecords = count(*)
FROM `data`
WHERE `year`='2017'
         AND `mark` =  '0133' 

IF @numrecords > 0 THEN
     UPDATE `data`
     SET `year` = '2017' , `mark` = '0133' ,`Timestamp` = '2010-01-14 23:30:00.000' 
     WHERE `year`='2017'
         AND `mark` =  '0133' 
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `data` (`year`, `mark`, `Timestamp`)
    VALUES ('2017', '0133', '2010-01-14 23:30:00.000')
END IF
```

Comment: Is **combination** of `year` and `mark` uique?

Comment: They are not unique, and are not combined in any way, they are values in separate columns and individually indexed (xyear, xmark).